# iterating over test case in java

Tags: java, arraylist

Input Format
The first line of input consist of number of test cases, T.

The first line of each test case consist of number of villains and player, N.

The second line of each test case consist of the N space separated strengths of Villains.

The third line of each test case consist of N space separated energy of players.

```
3
6
112 243 512 343 90 478 
500 789 234 400 452 150
6
10 20 50 100 500 400 
30 20 60 70 90 490 
5
10 20 30 40 50 
40 50 60 70 80
```

here i want to send the players & villains in separate arrays as the parameters to the function, here is my code but i am getting index out of bound exception 
at inner for loop when the number of test cases & size of the villains and players increases

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
List < Integer > values = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > temp = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > villain = new ArrayList < > ();
List < Integer > player = new ArrayList < > ();


 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 int n = scanner.nextInt();
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
 values.add(Integer.valueOf(scanner.next()));
  }

  scanner.close();


 int q = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

  for (int counter = q + 1; counter <= ((values.get(q) * 2) + q); counter++) 
 {

    if(counter < values.size())    
    temp.add(values.get(counter));

   if (counter == ((values.get(q) * 2) + q)) {
   for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) {
   if (j < temp.size() / 2)
   villain.add(temp.get(j));
  else
   player.add(temp.get(j));
 }
 String endresult = empire(villain, player);
 System.out.println(endresult);
 villain.clear();
 player.clear();

 }

   }
 temp.clear();
  q = (2 * values.get(q)) + 1;
  }

}
}
```

Comment: Make sure there is no output before "header" and  try with space in header _header("Location : $r");_

Comment: You have not set `$_SESSION['login']` any where!! Your this condition `&& ($_SESSION['login'] == true)` always `FALSE`

Comment: lot of things :- `session_start();` must be first line,not in middle.2. You have not set `$_SESSION['login']` any where!! 3. don't use deprecated `mysql_*` library. Please switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: Also from where the hell `$u` comes in your login.php?

Comment: $u is the username entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to place an `exit;` behind the header redirect. Otherwise, the code will be parsed to the end and any second redirect header or content output will overwrite the first header redirect.

Also, as saty pointed out, you have to set the `$_SESSION['login']` key if you're going to check for it. By the way, it's always better to use the `===` operator instead of `==` when checking for truly boolean values instead of allowing "falsy" and "truey" values.

Comment: his code having lot of bugs and errors, instead of these two.

Comment: thank you it's working now i have stuck up with another problem!!

Comment: logout.php<?php
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
header('location:login.php');
?>

interface.php

Answer (score 0):

After `header("Location: $f");` use `exit();` to force stop before the read below in the php code.

Hope it will help you.